# Select and Convert Date Of Birth from a table to check if their birthdays are today

Tags: sql-server, datetime, triggers, getdate

I have a table called Genericattribute. It's as shown here.

[image]

[image]

I need to make a Trigger or a query that checks if today is the birthday of any of these employees.

I wrote a query that returns the Ids of the people along with their birthdays.

```
select [id],[value] from [Genericattribute]
where [key] = 'DateOfBirth'
```

It returned this output.

[image]

The date of births here are of the int type. Not the Date type.

I am unable to figure out how I can write a query that converts these int values to the date.

I have tried to use the `getdate()` to check today's date/time.
Could not find any solution to figure this problem.

Comment: Please do not post image. Post the sample data and expected result as formatted text.

Comment: _The date of births here are of the int type._ They are not. It looks like your system is converting different types of data into formatted strings and storing them in columns using the `varchar` or `nvarchar` data type. This is not recommended - not only does it make performance suffer, it makes data more difficult to handle and leads to formatting errors. Have you read the [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles) documentation to see how to convert strings to `date` or `datetime` results?

Comment: @Squirrel Got you. Won't post pictures from my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought.  Since `[value]` appears to be a string.

```
where [key] = 'DateOfBirth'
  and right(value,5)=format(getdate(),'MM-dd')
```

I normally shy away from `format()` due to the performance issues, but in this example it would be resolved once.