# SQL stored procedure to determine age and changing the value of a row in another table depending upon the age

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-agent-job

This is a continuation of the previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75241903/select-and-convert-date-of-birth-from-a-table-to-check-if-their-birthdays-are-to).

So I have a table named GenericAttribute which has some values like this:

| Id | KeyGroup | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | Customer | DateOfBirth | 26-01-2000 |
| 29 | Customer | DateOfBirth | 26-01-2020 |
| 30 | Customer | CountryPage.HideStatesBlock | FALSE |

I have another table named RoleMapper that maps a customer based on their ID to their role ID. The Id in the GenericAttribute is the Foreign Key which originates from the CustomerID column of the RoleMapper table, below.

| CustomerID | CustomerRoleId |
| --- | --- |
| 28 | 58 |
| 29 | 27 |

My intention is to create a SQL agent job with a stored procedure that updates the RoleMapper table value to 24, if a customer's age is more than 60, today. The trigger must be activated once a day.

I am using SQL Server.

I tried using this query based on the answer given in my previous question.

```
select [id] from [Genericattribute]
where [key] = 'DateOfBirth'
  and right(value,5)=format(getdate(),'MM-dd')
```

Though I was able to get an answer to whose birthday was today, when more than one people had their birthdays on the same day, I was unable to proceed even after using a table data type.

Comment: `"The trigger must be activated once a day"` That is not how trigger works. If you want something to execute once a day, Schedule it using [SQL Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: And FYI Management Studio is purely a client UI to SQL Server. All the action takes place in SQL Server, not Management Studio.

Comment: And your query to detect whether today is the birthday will perform terribly because you are using functions on the column value in the where clause, which leaves SQL Server no option but to carry out a complete table scan and evaluate every single row in your table.

Comment: And nothing in your query indicates why it wouldn't work for multiple birthdays in one day.

Comment: Will use SQL Agent @Squirrel..

Comment: I missed to add that @DaleK. It was because I just used an int variable to assign the birthday. But I tried with a table as well & realized I'd have to modify the rest of the trigger.

Comment: How will I then scan the whole list of the birthdays, @DaleK?

Comment: if you stored you dateofbirth as a proper datetime column, with an index, you would be able to query `...where DateOfBirth < dateadd(year, -60, getdate())` and it would use the index to return you all clients who are over 60. You wouldn't normally store whether they are over 60, because you end up with the situation you are in.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server Agent why does your question still say trigger?

Comment: If you want to have the age of a customer, why not just use a computed colm against the DoB and the current date?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, I would argue that the EAV model is a strong indication of an ill-designed database, and you should consider, if possible at this point, redesgining your database.

Comment: Virtual tables inserted and deleted

Comment: To check what maded changes use these tables

Comment: The `inserted` and `deleted` tables don't they you what made the changes, @BogdanSahlean , they just contain the copies of the rows (that were effected) before and after the DML statement. The objects have no idea what made that DML statement.

Comment: Will try that out @Larnu

Comment: @ZoharPeled I agree but I'm helpless here to edit the design of the DB..

Comment: A more trivial issue that I found is that the Value hold date values in dd-MM-yyyy format (26-01-2000), but then you're comparing the day and month with MM-dd format.

Answer (score 1):

Try Schedule a SQL server agent job with the below query

```
--OLD QUERY
  --DECLARE @Today Date=GETDATE()
            
  --        ;WITH CTE
  --        AS
  --        (   
  --            SELECT  *,RIGHT(value,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(value,4,2)+'-'+LEFT(value,2)[Date]
  --            FROM    GenericAttribute
  --            WHERE   [key] = 'DateOfBirth'
  --        )
  --        UPDATE  RoleMapper
  --        SET     CustomerRoleId=24 
  --        FROM    RoleMapper RoleMapper
  --        JOIN    CTE
  --            ON  CTE.ID =RoleMapper.CustomerID
  --        WHERE   DATEDIFF(YEAR,[Date],@Today)>60 
  --            OR (DATEDIFF(YEAR,[Date],@Today)=60 AND MONTH(@Today)>=MONTH([Date]) AND DAY(@Today)>=DAY([Date]))
            
            DECLARE @Today Date=GETDATE()
            
            ;WITH CTE
            AS
            (   
                SELECT  * 
                FROM    GenericAttribute
                WHERE   [key] = 'DateOfBirth'
            )
        SELECT *
            FROM    RoleMapper  RoleMapper
            JOIN    CTE
                ON  CTE.ID =RoleMapper.CustomerID
            WHERE   DATEDIFF(YEAR,value,@Today)>60 
                OR (DATEDIFF(YEAR,value,@Today)=60 AND MONTH(@Today)>=MONTH(value) AND DAY(@Today)>=DAY(value))
```

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I got this error

Comment: Can you please confirm the result of below query are in same format ? ie, dd-MM-yyyy
SELECT  value
            FROM    GenericAttribute
            WHERE   [key] = 'DateOfBirth'

Comment: Hi, it comes in the YYYY-MM-DD format. Like this 1990-02-14
1937-02-14
1937-02-14
1912-01-01
1912-01-01

Comment: If all the date format is kept in the above manner tryabove query . (Updating the query above for readability)

Comment: May I know what's the "RoleMapper_75382441" in the select query?

Comment: Sorry , I was using different table names for my testing purpose . Table names  are corrected . Please check now.